# Is the Sorgenfrey Plane Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

I believe I am overthinking this problem, but I think the answer is no. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: The Sorgenfrey plane is the product of two spaces. A nonempty product of topological spaces is Hausdorff if and only if each factor is Hausdorff.

Comment: I was over thinking it. Also, I had misread the entire definition of the Sorgenfrey plane, which complicated things a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sorgenfrey Line is Hausdorff (and also $T_4$). For $a<b$ the set $[a,b)$ is a clopen set containing $a$ but not $b$.

Since the Sorgenfrey Plane is the square of the Sorgenfrey Line, it is Hausdorff being a product of Hausdorff spaces.